# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS consuming high CPU and RAM on HP EliteBook x360 1040 G7

Tags: google-chrome, battery, ram, cpu, overheating

I am experiencing an issue with my HP EliteBook x360 1040 G7 that's running Ubuntu 22.04. For the past few days my PC has been consuming high amounts of CPU and RAM, causing it to overheat and display a "CPU overthrottled" warning. Even with just two tabs open in Chrome, the system can consume up to 5GB of RAM, and opening Visual Studio Code can consume over 3GB of RAM. This is significantly affecting the battery life of my laptop, as it previously lasted for 7 hours, but now only lasts for 3-4 hours with just a few apps open.

I have tried several methods to resolve this issue, including checking for updates, disabling unnecessary startup applications, and scanning for malware. However, the issue persists, and every app I open seems to consume no less than 1GB of RAM. I am worried that this high resource usage could lead to permanent damage to my PC.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this issue, I would greatly appreciate it. I would prefer not to reinstall the OS, but I am willing to try any other solutions.

The screenshot shows how the CPU is getting consumed very fast. I have just 4 apps open: Chrome, VS Code, whatsdestop, Sublime Text and file manager.

[image: CPU USAGE IMAGE]

Comment: I see a make and model of the machine but what about how much ram you have what speed is the CPU?

Comment: My PC has 16gb of ram and Intel core i7 1.80ghz*8

Comment: I am also facing same issue with 16gb of RAM and 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-11390H @ 3.40GHz × 8
Please share if anyone can find workaround for this.